# install tensorflow on raspberry pi 4

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi4

when i type

```
pip install tensorflow
```

i get this error:

```
error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
error: no matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

then i tried to follow the step on https://medium.com/@rahulsri073/installing-tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi-1b2c8d1ee33c

and when i type the final step

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-2.9.0-cp39-none-linux_aarch64.whl
```

i get this error:

```
error: tensorflow-2.9.0-cp39-none-linux-arrch64.whl is not a supported 
wheel on this platform
```

anyone know how to solve?

python version: 3.9.2
pip version: 24.0

Comment: It seems like you are encountering compatibility issues with installing TensorFlow on your Raspberry Pi with a specific Python version and platform architecture.Ensure that  TensorFlow version you are trying to install is compatible with your Python version (3.9.2) and platform architecture (aarch64 for Raspberry Pi). Not all TensorFlow versions may support every platform and Python version combination.If you are still facing issues with the installation,check TensorFlow release notes [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow)repository&[Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)